# What books Napoleon Bonaparte used to read?

Tags: book, napoleon

I am interested to know the books that Napoleon Bonaparte had read,and perhaps make a list about it. According to a [Quora's answer](https://www.quora.com/How-many-books-did-Napoleon-Bonaparte-read), Napoleon had read:

- Rousseau - La Nouvelle Héloïse, the Social Contract
- Voltaire’s biography of Charles XII

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: From [Napoleon on War](http://www.napoleonguide.com/maxim_war.htm): "*Read over and over again the campaigns of Alexander, Hannibal, Caesar, Gustavus, Turenne, Eugene and Frederick ... This is the only way to become a great general and master the secrets of the art of war.*"

Comment: He also read The Prince in several occasions, and there is a version of Machiavelli's book with Napoleon's notes.

Comment: Quick google, this is the first result: https://shannonselin.com/2015/02/napoleon-like-read/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the German Wikipedia [on Napoleon](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_Bonaparte):

- Plato
- Voltaire
- Corneille
- Lavater
- Rollin "Geschichte des Altertums"
- Buffon "Histoire naturelle"
- Marigny "Geschichte der Araber"
- Goethe "Die Leiden des jungen Werthers"
- Rousseau
- Raynal.

[Source (sic) given in Wikipedia is 
Franz Herre: Napoleon Bonaparte. Eine Biographie. München 2006, S. 12–18, Volker Ullrich: Napoleon. Reinbek bei Hamburg 2004, S. 16–22.]

From the English Wikipedia [on James MacPherson, a Scottish writer and politician:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Macpherson)

- James MacPherson "Ossian", Italian translation by Melchiore Cesarotti (thanks to @Drux for pointing it out).

[Source given in Wikipedia is
Zamoyski, Adam (2001). Holy Madness: Romantics, Patriots and Revolutionaries. London: Weidenfeld & Nicolson. p. 45.]

Comment: James MacPherson (Ossian) should be on that list.